# Django form - initial value filter

Tags: python, django

I have a Form

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    #...
    src_lang = forms.ChoiceField(choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    tgt_lang = forms.ChoiceField(choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
```

and I set initial value for `src_lang` in this way:

```
uploadform = UploadForm(initial={'src_lang':'de'})
return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form':uploadform})
```

so far, so good.

now I need to filter out `'de'` from `tgt_lang` (so that `tgt_lang` doesnot show it) before rendering to template. how can I do it?

Comment: So will src_lang always be 'de' or will it be dynamical?

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer src_lang is dynamic, but I have it always in my hand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the constructor of the `UploadForm`.  Something like this:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        src_lang = self.initial.get('src_lang')
        if src_lang:
            choices = [(code, lang) for (code, lang) in settings.LANGUAGES
                                    if code != src_lang]
            self.fields['tgt_lang'].choices = choices
            self.fields['tgt_lang'].widget.choices = choices
```

Comment: Note that there was an error in the `if` condition.  It should be `if code != src_lang`.  I ahd updated the answer.

Comment: I am getting ``'UploadForm' object has no attribute 'fields'``

Comment: Hm, every django form has `fields` attribute after the initialization.  I just tested this code and it works just fine.  Can you update the question with the actual code of `__init__` you use?

Comment: dang it, I made a typo. now it is working! :D thanks bro